# Having no style in Chrome Webdriver (Selenium) as Firefox menu built function

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I'm recently using selenium chrome webdriver to scrape some data of simple websites, now I'm targeting to lower the time it takes to open the page. I have found the list of parameters I can turn off in Chrome - link1, now I'm wondering what are the functions Mozilla Firefox automatically turns off when I simple click "no style" on the browser menu.

I sucessfully turned off images, but I think there are other things to disable.

> prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":1,}

link1 : http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-application-cache

*** Edit: I have already tried PhantomJS, I have tested it and apearently it took more time to load pages than chrome.

Comment: Taking this in a different direction... are you running multiple instances of your script? I have run scripts that place thousands of orders on a website. I can run 4 (or however many) instances of the script at once which means that the task is accomplished 4x as fast. Split the task into 4 pieces and run four scripts, each on its own piece. That will speed your task completion more significantly than loading a page without css, images, etc.

Comment: I think I got it, but in my case is a simple scrape (just prices) that's why the page loading is more relevant than the scrape itself. Then imagine that running over and over, that's too much time spent with loading page.